# What is the exclamation mark in the bottom right corner for in Photos for iOS?

Tags: ios, photos.app

When looking at a photo in Apple's Photos.app I noticed a white  exclamation mark in the bottom right corner of a photo. What does that indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tapping around a bit I tapped on **Edit** and a message popped up that said there was any issue downloading the photo over cellular. I guess it was just a thumbnail. I recently turned on iCloud Photo Library and turned off cellular data for photos. Turning cellular data back on removed the exclamation mark.